# Op Amp input protection

Tags: operational-amplifier, protection, input

I was looking for an Op Amp input protection circuit and the most common I found looks like this.

When the voltage at `Input Signal` goes above/below Op-Amp's supply rails schottkey diodes start to conduct.

Let's assume a +100V is applied at `Vin`. 
A current equal to `I = (100V - (+15V) - 0.7V) / 5kΩ = 16.86mA` will flow from the upper diode to positive supply rail.

The question is, how dangerous is that current flowing to supply rails therefore to the circuit power supply? Would it cause damage to power supply if that amount of voltage is permanent and not transient?

[image]

Comment: This circuit is meant to dump ESD to power capacitors (not shown in the schematic). It is not meant to protect against prolonged over voltage on input signal. There is already an answer to the question with explanation why.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you only want to know how how dangerous this circuit is, or, would you like to know a better way to protect your circuit? There are many different ways to do this. Depends on whether you want DC or not and what do you want to do with the excessive energy (block it or dump it) and other factors.

Comment: I'd like to know both! Yes I can think of few other ways but as you said it depends on what you're after. I'd like to know a way to deal with excessive energy when a big DC voltage applied to input and how dangerous is that energy to a circuit like that I posted in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100Vdc could fuse open Rovp if it is not rated for 2W.

100Vdc could damage LDO's.

- Most LDO's are emitter followers, so they source but not sink or pull down.
  Thus it could try to use the 100Vdc input to pullup Vcc to 85V or damage the LDO, so a CA type TVS is recommended on input or as OVP protection to protect supply.

This Op Amp has input pins with clamp diodes to the power supply pins and to each
other. Limit the input current to 10 mA or less whenever input signals
exceed the power supply rail by 0.3 V.

This Op Amp is CMOS so all precautions to prevent sensor or input/output voltage pullup before Op Amp power is applied must be done.

It is somewhat rugged with 6kV finger ESD protection as long as above precautions are added if expected.

Comment: If input voltage was significant less than 100Vdc (say 5Vdc above/below supply rails) would still cause damage to an LDO. So what's the purpose of clamp diodes if other parts of the circuit get damaged?

Comment: Would an extra zener diode on supply rail prevent voltage to rise above/fall below supply limits?

Comment: 1) Perhaps, so you will find reverse diodes from Out to IN on LDO's  to protect that fault condition in datashsheet .  ESD can cause shoothru-failure  on CMOS  if load exceeds 5mA on input outside rail. from Rs of diode. Go read .about it  2) Zener yes, but TVS is better.

Comment: TVS diode would be damanged if applied voltage stay on the input line for a long period of time.


Also, I found that interesting topic that answers my question at 99%
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139215/long-term-effect-of-over-voltage-on-clamping-diodes-and-adc-reference-voltage

Comment: Of course every Clamp diode must have a power limiting source impedance to perform as an attenuator, which is my 1st answer ( your fuse)

Comment: Could Rovp (resistor at input) take that role?

Comment: Yes just increase it to 50k and consider Iin offset or use on both inputs Rfb,Rovp, to null input current offset voltage, but this also lowers immunity to stray B field noise ( current loop transients)

Comment: To clarify your comment, when you talk about TVS you mean Dovp ? To replace schottkey with TVS or just an extra parallel diode at each supply rail?

Comment: I meant in addition. to, but please define all your worst case inputs before starting any design.  .. e.g. IEC immunity and why do you need 100Vdc protection?

Comment: I want to be able to get measurement at highest resolution (using different -software controlled- voltage divider ratios) without damaging any parts of the circuit in case a greater voltage occurs. Voltage divider would affect system resolution pretty much if any consideration would be carried out at worst case of 100Vdc or so.

Comment: OK then you want differential R-DAC with specs on immunity, noise reduction, CM impedance and Diff input impedance like any DMM

Comment: In addition to CM noise reduction you want to specify DM noise & RF immunity and BW. SO make a list of design specs for all noise and signal requirements impedance, voltage and BW to avoid errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89815/discussion-between-mrbit-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).